# AudioRecord audio capture

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

When initializing `AudioRecord`, one of the parameters are the `AudioSource`.

When I'm using the `AudioSource.DEFAULT`, there is no processing in audio input.

But when I'm using `AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION`, the recorder audio is processed by filters.

How can I know the filters were applied in the captured audio?

Comment: There really isn't any way, because it varies between different vendors and devices.

Comment: How can I know the filters for the most big players (as SAMSUNG, MOTOROLA)? Where I can find the source code?

Comment: To my knowledge you simply can't because their source code is not open.